# Building a GUI in Netbeans, which should I use?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

I am building a GUI in Netbeans - it is for a simple little application - a converter program.  Basically, user types whatever it is they want to convert into a text field, selects the conversion from a number of radio buttons (say lbs to kg) and then clicks "Convert".

The thing is, I want the "Convert" button and the radio buttons to behave like this:

1. Radio buttons and "Convert" button are disabled when program loads.
2. Radio buttons and "Convert" button will become enabled if user types a number (and only a number) into the text field.
3. If used deletes what they have typed, everything will be disabled again until they type in another number.

I have managed to set the Radio buttons and "Convert" button up so they are disabled, by unchecking the "enabled" box in the properties for each component.  I have also been able to use a simple if statement and the keyTyped event to enable/disable as follows:

```
private void txtUsrInputKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
{                                     
    if (!txtUsrInput.getText().equals(""))
    {
        btnCalculate.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        btnCalculate.setEnabled(false);            
    }
}
```

I want to extend my code so that if the user accidentally types a letter or symbol into the text field (don't ask me why they'd do that, when they know they must only type a number) then the program will *either* ignore what they typed, or display an error.  The exception to this is, of course, typing a period (.) because they might want to indicate a decimal number.

Any thoughts on how I might do this?  Hope what I wrote makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

**Your GUI**

If you do not already know swing, then *learn it*. Knowing how all of the components work is always a huge advantage for any developer, and if anything goes wrong, you know exactly how to fix it (or at least have a much better chance). Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) stuff, for some help on getting started.

**Checking for a decimal**

This looks like a job for regular expressions. What you can do is specify a number `[0-9]`, and a period, `\.`. Then ensure that either a number or a decimal is typed a certain amount of times. The important thing to note here though, is that the user can only type *one* decimal, which winds up being:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))
```

This will allow values like `9`, `0.9`, `1.9302`. It will *not* allow values like `.901`. If you wish to allow that, simple swap the first `+` for a `*`.:

```
([0-9]*(\.[0-9]+))
```

**Using it**

Because a text box contains a string, you can compare it with your regex. Simply:

```
if(textBox1.getText().matches("([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))")) {
    // Run some code in here.
}
```

Comment: Chris - thanks for the info on the Regex, and thanks for the info on GUI creation!

Comment: Ok, so now I have a new problem! The regex above works perfectly when I run the jar file in Ubuntu 12.04.  But if I boot into Windows XP, and run the Jar from there, the regex doesn't work!  Anything I enter produces an error, even if I enter the correct data.

Comment: That's because this regex is built to run on later versions of Java. What version of java is running on the Windows XP machine?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if GUI is simple, DO NOT use GUI Builder, but code from scratch. Following harder path, you will learn about layouts, actionlisteners and so on ...